# Resizing Hash Map with Linear Probing

Tags: hashmap, linear-probing

[Problem Screenshot**strong text**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1CoX.png)
I am not sure why my answer is incorrect. Can anyone tell me whay I am doing wrong without giving my the answer? Thanks in advance.
The problem states:
Suppose we have the following HashMap using linear probing, where the keys are integers, and the values are not shown. The hash function is the identity function, and the compression function is modulo like usual.

[ 0 _ _ _ 4 5X 6 18 8X _ _ 11 24]

Suppose we decide to shrink the table to length 9. We perform this resize by considering the entries from left to right in the original table. What is the new table? Input your answer as the following form as an array with no commas, just single spaces. Null spots can be denoted by an underscore _. For example, if we were to write down the original table in the format we want, then it would be "[0 _ _ _ 4 5X 6 18 8X _ _ 11 24]".

My incorrect answer is: [0 18 11 _ 4 5X 6 24 8X]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When resizing, the `DEL` markers are set to null.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me
[0 18 11 _ 4 _ 6 24 _]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).